# Iptables setup on VPN client having LAN

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, openvpn

I am struggling with some problem, probably because there is simply not enough information on the web regarding some specifics I am trying to setup.

I have bought OpenVPN service via tun (routing).
I connect to the OpenVPN server through Raspberry PI (serving me as router), which has two interfaces - `eth0` for handling Internet connection and `wlan0` for my internal LAN.

My goal is to setup firewall in such way, that I can filter `tun`-ned income traffic and be able to reach web from LAN behind `wlan0`. Also - everything should go via VPN.

From the architectural point of view I think it should look like this:

- `INPUT`, `FORWARD` - dropped,
- `OUTPUT` - allowed,
- `eth0` allows to flow only packets via default OpenVPN service port,
- `tun` adapter should have all INPUT-related policies applied and should be NAT-ted.

What you think - is this correct thinking? I have managed so far to be able to ping from SSH-ed Raspberry PI into web, but yet no DNS - do I understand correctly that I should have own DNS forwarder? DHCP server is set on Raspberry PI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved the issue. For those which are interested - incoming packets from LAN are processed by openvpn client (tun/tap), then passed over internet-facing interface. So it was a mater of setting correct forwarding between interfaces. /etc/resolv.conf just had to been overwritten with global (like Google) DNSes to solve ping-related problem.